# Should i use both backend and frontend form validation?

Tags: validation, zend-framework2, frontend, backend

I have been using so far back end form validation using Zend Framework 2 input filter. I was wondering if usually front end validation should also be used because there are plenty js frameworks that make it easy. I am afraid that if I use only frontend validation some users could disable js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use front end validation for the UI, because you can make it fluid and more appealing for the user. You are right about disabling js, thats why you need backend validation too. I am using both, for the fluid look and for the security